# Advice on why Chrome console will change value

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

Sort of new here, been lurking in the wings for years, and I am stuck hoping someone can give me hand.

I am trying to automate a repetitive task for work using DOM for AutoHotKey in internet explorer. I can't for the life of me get my 'number' to fill into an element on IE.

I am using IE 11. The inspect element is.

```
<input name="claimNo" class="bodyText" id="claimNo" type="Text" size="10" maxlength="6" value="" lpcachedvisval="1" lpcachedvistime="1484754693">
```

I tried writing a basic script to test,

```
#SingleInstance force

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := true
wb.Toolbar := False
wb.Navigate("work_URL")


while (wb.readystate!=4) 

Sleep, 100 

Sleep, 1000

workorder_number := wb.document.getElementById("claimNo")

workorder_number.Value := 123456
```

and it doesn't work.

I tried simply controlling the webpage with the console built in.
Using the console in IE11, I type, `document.getElementByID("claimNo").value = 123456;`

I get error:  `Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference`

Out of curiousity. I loaded my webpage into Google Chrome, and tried the exact same process, and it fills in the 'claimNo' element no problem.

Is there something I am missing? Can anyone help me?

Comment: `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`

Comment: Thanks for catching that, I tried it and still same error on console.

Comment: I think you might be trying to fill the element, before the element starts existing, leading to the error message you get. You don't get the message when you type it in console, because the page is fully loaded by the time you hit enter and send your command.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the latest version of AHK(1.1.24.04) and wrote this, which worked:

```
#u::
wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := true
wb.Toolbar := False
wb.Navigate("whatever URL")
while (wb.busy or wb.ReadyState != 4)
    Sleep, 100
workorder_number := wb.document.getElementById("whateverFieldID")
workorder_number.Value := 123456
return
```

[Basic Webpage Controls with JavaScript / COM](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/47052-basic-webpage-controls-with-javascript-com-tutorial/)

Comment: Appreciate your help. This code works on other webpages, but doesn't seem to want to work on my main work website.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
workorder_number.innerText := 123456
```

Input Element expects text input from the user. Internet Explorer has a built in DOM element .innerText that just works more reliably, if a bit slower than .textContent, than other methods for retrieving and setting text in forms. Read about it here: http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/

Example of it's use on a Form here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41733944/1914172

Also OP's issue might be as someone else stated, that the forms haven't fully loaded, even if the web page has reported that it finished via ReadyState, some generated page content might not have. A work around for this is like so:

```
#SingleInstance force

wb := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
wb.Visible := true
wb.Toolbar := False
wb.Navigate("work_URL")


while (wb.busy or wb.ReadyState != 4)
    sleep 100

Sleep, 1000

workorder_number := wb.document.getElementById("claimNo")

ComObjError(False)
while (workorder_number.innerText == "")
    workorder_number.innerText := 123456
ComObjError(True)
```

Comment: innerHTML results in the same error for me, with or without your new snippet of code at the bottom.  I have this code working on other websites (UPS to log in, create a shipment), but this site just doesn't want to accept any of my code.

Comment: I think I have sourced my problem to frames. I don't understand them.  Can you assist me in accessing a specific frame on my web page, then I think my code will work

Comment: Frames are different beast all together, they can be tricky to work with. I'd re-post a new question, or at the very least edit this one with a link to a website or some more HTML code for us to go by. If the site contains sensitive info you can't share, find a generic site with frames you can to ask your questions about retrieving data from them.